# How to find limit of a probability of a continuous random variable with geometric distribution?

Tags: probability

**Problem 5.** A box contains $n$ balls, $k$ of them are white ($k<n$), and $n-k$ are black. Suppose we take balls from the box until we get a white one, each time returning a ball back to the box. Let $X$ be the number of attempts until we get a white ball.

(a) What is the distribution of $X$? What is $E(X_n)$?

(b) Find the probability that we will make more than $n$ attemts, and find the limit of this probability as $n\to\infty$.

(c) Let $Y=X/n$ be the ratio of the number of attempts to the number of balls in the box. For any number $t\ge0$ find the probability $P(Y\le t)$ and find the limit of this probability as $n\to\infty$.

(d) Denote by $F(t)$ the limit that you have found in the previous question. Is $F$ a cumulative distribution function? If so, of what distribution?

---

I need to solve this problem. I managed to do (a), which was rather obvious ($X\sim\operatorname{Geometric}(k/n), E(X_n)=n/k$), but I struggle to do (b), (c), (d).

It seemed to me that in (b) $P(X>n)=1-P(X<n)=1-F(n)$, but this just leads nowhere, since I am not sure how to derive the cdf.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Let $p = \frac{k}{n}$ and $q = 1-p$. Then $P(X=x) = q^{(x-1)}p$ and $P(X \leq x) = \sum_{t=1}^xq^{(t-1)}p$.

You just need to work through some algebra. All the best!

P.S.
Here is an excellent reference on typing mathematical formula in your future questions and answers: [MathJax Basics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/)